# toggle menu icon doesn't show before first click (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, icons, toggle

I am trying to implement a toggle menu in wordpress without using a plug-in. Everything works fine, except the toggle menu icon doesn't show, until i press the "missing image" icon - then it shows up.

My js look like this (slidepanel.js)

```
    (function($) {
$('#toggle').toggle( 
    function() {
        $('#popout').animate({ left: 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#toggle').html('<img src="http://localhost:8080/theme/wp-content/themes/theme/images/menu.png" alt="close" />');
        });
    }, 
    function() {
        $('#popout').animate({ left: -360 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#toggle').html('<img src="http://localhost:8080/theme/wp-content/themes/theme/images/menu.png" alt="close" />');
        });
    }
);
})(jQuery);
```

my functions.php looks like this

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpb_slidepanel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slidepanel.js', array('jquery'), '20160909', true );
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show how the HTML is written and displayed?

Comment: Sounds like you are not including the image in your html, or that its not being included correctly. As the comment above says, please show us your HTML so we can see exactly whats happening. Take a look at how to include a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have the information we need to help!

Comment: Sorry, for my late reply. Thank You!!! You where right - I've had a wrong href link to the icon in my php/html. Now everything works fine!!!